# Linker Error: Unable to open file 'CHARTGROUPFRAME.DFM'

Tags: linker, c++builder, c++builder-2007

My IDE has been working very well, until today.

When I try to compile my project, I get this :

> [Linker Error] Unable to open file 'CHARTGROUPFRAME.DFM'

CHARTGROUPFRAME.CPP Unit is a part of a project, so this is a bug of course.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a workoutaround for this problem :) .

I've only needed to add  a directory in which .DFM file resides to  my  **Library Path**

Btw, this is supposed to be set by the IDE when I add a unit to the project ... but , at least this works :)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem also in RAD Studio 10.1, for me it helped to close the editor pane where these files were open.

Comment: I was using RAD Studio 10.4.2 as administrator, converting an older Borland C++ project. I had to make an insignificant change to the form in the editor to force it to want to save. Then I closed the file, saved it and it successfully linked. A similar problem exists in Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Run your RAD Studio from Administrator.